# Android change videoview size inside the framelayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-videoview, android-framelayout

I have a framelayout that has an imageview and videoview, and the videoview is on the top of the imageview.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imgFrameId"
        android:background="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vidFrameId"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

They are the same size so my videoview covers my imageview, but I don't want that. How can I reduce my videoview's size into 50% (50% of width and height)? I tried many ways but none worked, most will reduce the size to a ratio, I want it to perfectly decrease, like if the original is 500dp, it would be 250dp.

Comment: 50% of original height and width or 50% of the framelayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068242/does-android-support-scaling-video) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video/4452597#4452597) you should extend the VideoView class in a custom class and in the onMeasure method make the changes.

In terms of code this would look like the following :

```
 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
 int width = widthMeasureSpec/2 ;
 int height = heightMeasureSpec/2 ;

 setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
 }
```

Let me know if you need more help with this.